# Thread join(1) usage in mutlithread wait-notify example in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have example with wait-notify application which is invoked from main:

```
public class Handler {

public void producer () throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    synchronized(this) {
        System.out.println("Producer started ######...");
        wait();
        System.out.println("Proceed running in current thread after notification and 5s sleep in consumer tread");
    }
}

public void consumer() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    synchronized(this) {
        System.out.println("Consumer started #####...");
        notify();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

}
```

}

and invoker

```
public class ThreadRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            handler.producer();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            handler.consumer();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    
    
    try {
        thread1.join(1);
        thread2.join(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("exception");
    }
}
```

}

As I expected "exception" message should be printed as I join(1) to threads and wait them to die only 1 mills, but they are sleeping more than that. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`join(1)` has 3 ways 'out':

- The thread you called `join` on ends, in which case your call to `join(1)` stops running by returning.
- Some code someplace (it's only code that can do it, e.g. a user pressing CTRL+C or whatnot never causes this) calls `.interrupt()` on your thread; `join(1)` stops running by throwing `InterruptedException`.
- **1 milliseconds passes, in which case `join(1)` stops running by returning.**

You are evidently under the impression that the join method exits by way of throwing InterruptedEx if the time runs out. It does not.